# how to input content to a cell without create a new excel document?

Tags: c#

now I am working on a project using c# to built a console application, which is to add more functions based on Excel. For example, SUM() is already built in the Excel. I try to add other functions that could work as the same way as SUM().(once the user click on the function button, the function will showed in the excel's active cell with parameters that need to be passed. If user click on like cell B1:A1, the content in B1:A1 will show as one of the parameters in this function. Just work exactly same as how SUM() function work in excel). My question is, if there is a way that I could input the function into the cell without creating a new worksheet. Every time I run the program, it will show a excel itself. And all the function will showed in this excel. So I don't want to create another excel, instead I want to use this excel to achieve all the functions. 
this is what I get:

//export is a button, user could click on this button, and the corresponding function should show in the cell. (should in the active cell, but I will figure it out later). 
//this give me a new worksheet
//because every time I run the program, the program showed me a worksheet. I want to use this worksheet. 
 private void export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

        xla.Visible = true;
        //index from 1

        ws.Cells[2, 1] = trans1.Text;
        ws.Cells[3, 1] = trans2.Text;
        ws.Cells[4, 1] = trans3.Text;

    }
```

I don't know if I express my question clearly. My English is not that good, but feel free to ask me. 
very appreciate for helps!

Comment: sorry, I get to change my question. Now I know how to ask more accurately. So, my question is that, now I am using Excel-dna to do the project, but I don't know how to write string to the cell without create a new excel? very appreciate for help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it! it is really easy.

```
Excel.Application xlapp = (Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
Excel.Workbook wbook = xlapp.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet wsheet = wbook.ActiveSheet;
```